# Image to walls of maze

Tags: image

[image]

I want to add an image file to the maze created but i am unable to find the color option to make the edit.

Comment: open up the "*Diffuse*" section over on the right. To change the color, but to add a texture go to the texture tab.

Answer (score 2):

If i understood the question 1st think notice is that your in Blender Game

**If you want to color**

Go to the Material Tab -> click on Diffuse below

[image]

[image]

Change the color as per needed

**If you want to apply textures**

Click the texture tab -> click New

[image]

Select below Image / movie option and below that select open and access the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the node editor and create an image texture node. Open the image file, and then attach the image color to the color socket of your Material.001 Diffuse BSDF shader. You may have to do a UV unwrap to get the desired placement.